# Calling function in inlined C library

Tags: c, perl, inline

I'm trying to make a simple wrapper around the [CommonMark](https://github.com/jgm/CommonMark) C library using [Inline::C](https://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::C). I have installed `libcmark.so` in `/usr/local/lib/`.

My current code looks like this:

```
package Text::CommonMark;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub commonmarker {
    my $text = shift;
    return commonmark_to_html($text);
}

use Inline C => qq{

    char* commonmark_to_html(char* thetext) {

        char* result = cmark_markdown_to_html(thetext, strlen(thetext));
        return result;
    }
} => LIBS => '-L/usr/local/lib/ -llibcmark.so';

1;
```

When using `commonmarker` from a script I get:

```
perl: symbol lookup error: /home/erik/sublimeworks/dists/Text-CommonMark/_Inline/lib/auto/Text/CommonMark_33fb/CommonMark_33fb.so: undefined symbol: cmark_markdown_to_html
```

I assume that my call to `cmark_markdown_to_html` doesn't match its signature, but all signatures for `cmark_markdown_to_html` that I've [found](https://github.com/jgm/CommonMark/blob/master/src/cmark.h#L30) look like this:

```
char *cmark_markdown_to_html(const char *text, int len)
```

I haven't touched either C or Inline::C before so I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Tip: Using `q{}` instead of `qq{}` means you have to escape far less. Better yet, using `<<'EOC'` means you don't have to escape anything at all.

Comment: I don't think it's a mismatched prototype. I think the symbol isn't found in the library, or the library itself isn't found. `perl -MInline=force,info,noclean script.pl` might provide more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No mentioned of `LIBS` in the docs. The option is named `libs`.

```
use Inline C => config => libs => '-L/usr/local/lib/ -llibcmark.so';
use Inline C => <<'__EOC__';

    char* commonmark_to_html(char* thetext) {
        char* result = cmark_markdown_to_html(thetext, strlen(thetext));
        return result;
    }

__EOC__
```

---

Note that using `char* thetext` as an argument to an XS function is a sure sign of a bug. That gives you a pointer to the string buffer without telling you the format of the buffer.

Assuming the library accepts and returns text encoded using UTF-8,

```
SV* commonmark_to_html(SV* text_sv) {
    STRLEN text_len;
    const char* text = SvPVutf8(text_sv, text_len);
    const char* html = cmark_markdown_to_html(text, text_len);
    SV* html_sv = newSVpvn_flags(html, strlen(html), SVf_UTF8);
    free(html);
    return html_sv;
}
```

Optimized slightly (since having `newSVpvn_flags` mortalize the scalar is more efficient that having the typemap-generated code call `sv_2mortal`):

```
void commonmark_to_html(SV* text_sv) {
    STRLEN text_len;
    const char* text = SvPVutf8(text_sv, text_len);
    const char* html = cmark_markdown_to_html(text, text_len);
    SV* html_sv = newSVpvn_flags(html, strlen(html), SVf_UTF8|SVs_TEMP);
    free(html);
    ST(0) = html_sv;
    XSRETURN(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

I'm guessing that should be:

    ... => config => libs => ...

('Invalid usage of Inline module.' without the 'libs => ')

Still getting the same error though.

I got the 'LIBS' from Inline::C::Cookbook.

Comment: @Csson, Oops, yeah, fixed. Well, then either the library doesn't contains the symbol `cmark_markdown_to_html`, or it can't find the library. The latter should cause a warning to appear for `perl -MInline=force,info,noclean script.pl`.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: The entire inlined function... :)

Comment: I mean, what was the solution to the problem you asked about? You mentioned that my fix didn't help, but now you say everything is ok. We should document the actual solution for future readers.

Comment: The first fix (changing around libs and so) didn't work (because my function didn't work). Using your 'SV* commonmark_to_html(SV* text_sv)' solution does work. So now I have a good reason to learn a little C.

Comment: You asked about a symbol error. Only one of the changes I made could have fixed that, and you said it didn't. So what fixed that error?

Answer (score 2):

Your `-l` argument looks suspect. Usually the compiler/linker will prefix the "lib" and suffix the ".so", so normally you should just need to supply

```
-lcmark
```

Comment: It actually works either way, but that is good to know. Thanks!